# How to generate, read and delete a temporary csv-file with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a function that processes a csv file.

How can I generate the file (with specified content) using pytest, run the test on that file, and delete the file again?

Answer (score 3):

I used a fixture. It seems to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def csv_file(tmpdir_factory):
    N = 10
    index = range(N)
    even = [(n % 2 == 0) for n in range(N)]
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'even': even}, index=index) 
    filename = str(tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data').join('data.csv'))
    dataframe.to_csv(filename)
    return filename


def some_test(csv_file):
    pass
```